# What is the correct way to define nested object in generic class?

Tags: typescript

I want to define nested objects in my `SidenavOptions` class.

```
export class SidenavOptions {
    autoWidth: boolean;
    container: {
        styles: {
            width: string,
            height: string,
            backgroundColor: string,
        }
    };
}
```

and using in my component like:

```
bindOptions(): SidenavOptions {
    this.hasOptions = new SidenavOptions();
    this.hasOptions.container.styles.backgroundColor = "black";
    debugger
    return this.hasOptions;
  }
```

it shows me error in browser console:

[image]

what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `strictPropertyInitialization` is not set to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`.  If it is set, you should be seeing this type error:

> Property 'container' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)

[See the error on this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCWATApgOzANwPIAcAu8A9qjAN4CwAUNDdGAK56EDqSeAFgFzQBGhhIZGFQBuKrWjBieMPFTIATtwrUJtCHgCegiMvFqDAdzZdoGhXIDmAGn0GJ7ZPEvs83c1dur7tHmGAA1pYKhPSoiADCAoRKZngWqDZ2agC+ySlilGmUVFIkeNCE+EQk0AC80PKGcEhomLgExBAAFACUVEWNJAB0eTJyit0a2sgQ3X6BwaHhUSAx5dAA5DzggYu5TQLI3XOWzYuGMQEQi61AA)

All you've done is set the type of the class properties, but you are not actually setting a value. So when you call `this.hasOptions.container.styles`, `container` is undefined, so you get the crash.

You need to actually initialize your class with values. If you add a constructor that is something like:

```
    constructor() {
      this.autoWidth = true
      this.container = {
        styles: {
          width: '100px',
          height: '100px',
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
```

Then it should work as you expect:

```
const options = new SidenavOptions()
options.container.styles.backgroundColor = 'black'
// works!
```

[Working example on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCWATApgOzANwPIAcAu8A9qjAN4CwAUNDdGAK56EDqSeAFgFzQBGhhIZGFQBuKrWjBieMPFTIATtwrUJtCHgCegiMvFqDAdzZdoGhXIDmAGn0GJ7ZPEvs83c1dur7tHmGAA1pYKhPSoiADCAoRKZngWqDZ2agC+ySlilMlSJPH0wEwKABQAlNAqBhzwEAB0DEysiBzQALzQecjJNFW1OTJyiq3lXepaOnre9sZNpgDkAIwADIs4AB6zXj40js6u3AvLaxsjEn6BwaHhUSAx+wrIiLMn0GmTNK8Sr69UORrQhPgiCQhvJDHAkGhMLgCMQIKUqACYSQan1ZPIFDUNNpkLUzkEQmFItEFENZjxwIEnpRfgJkDUbpYirNDDEAhBZiUgA)